# android splash screen not working

Tags: android, multithreading, splash-screen

hi there  i have seen a tutorial here (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=embeFCPzRCg)
in which just a splash screen comes and then other  main screen comes... the code in the video is working fine ... but when i coded my self an error occurs in the log cat and splash screen comes but before going to the next screen the application crashes.

log file error

Blockquote

```
06-12 14:34:45.195: I/dalvikvm-heap(25510): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.376MB for 519700-byte allocation

06-12 14:34:45.240: D/dalvikvm(25510): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 8% free 12731K/13831K, paused 13ms+2ms, total 45ms

06-12 14:34:45.310: D/libEGL(25510): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so

06-12 14:34:45.320: D/libEGL(25510): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so

06-12 14:34:45.325: D/libEGL(25510): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so

06-12 14:34:45.325: D/(25510): Device driver API match

06-12 14:34:45.325: D/(25510): Device driver API version: 10

06-12 14:34:45.325: D/(25510): User space API version: 10 

06-12 14:34:45.325: D/(25510): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 
15:37:13 KST 2012 

06-12 14:34:45.365: D/OpenGLRenderer(25510): Enabling debug mode 0

06-12 14:34:46.275: W/dalvikvm(25510): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x411292a0)

06-12 14:34:46.280: E/AndroidRuntime(25510): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11666

06-12 14:34:46.280: E/AndroidRuntime(25510): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.edoc_dc/com.example.edoc_dc.Main}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

06-12 14:34:46.280: E/AndroidRuntime(25510):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1545)

06-12 14:34:46.280: E/AndroidRuntime(25510):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1420)

06-12 14:34:46.280: E/AndroidRuntime(25510):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3446)

06-12 14:34:46.280: E/AndroidRuntime(25510):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3407)

06-12 14:34:46.280: E/AndroidRuntime(25510):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3617)

06-12 14:34:46.280: E/AndroidRuntime(25510):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3585)

06-12 14:34:46.280: E/AndroidRuntime(25510):    at com.example.edoc_dc.Edoc_dc$1.run(Edoc_dc.java:28)

06-12 14:34:46.320: I/Process(25510): Sending signal. PID: 25510 SIG: 9
06-12 14:35:12.360: W/dalvikvm(25869): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x411292a0)

06-12 14:35:12.360: E/AndroidRuntime(25869): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11681

06-12 14:35:12.360: E/AndroidRuntime(25869): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.edoc_dc/com.example.edoc_dc.Main}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

06-12 14:35:12.360: E/AndroidRuntime(25869):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1545)

06-12 14:35:12.360: E/AndroidRuntime(25869):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1420)

06-12 14:35:12.360: E/AndroidRuntime(25869):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3446)

06-12 14:35:12.360: E/AndroidRuntime(25869):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3407)

06-12 14:35:12.360: E/AndroidRuntime(25869):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3617)

06-12 14:35:12.360: E/AndroidRuntime(25869):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3585)

06-12 14:35:12.360: E/AndroidRuntime(25869):    at com.example.edoc_dc.Edoc_dc$1.run(Edoc_dc.java:28)
```

this is my splash screen code which is to b loaded first edoc_dc.java

```
  package com.example.edoc_dc;

  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.MenuItem;
  import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

  public class Edoc_dc extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edoc_dc);


// meke the thread here

    Thread splash_screen= new Thread(){
        public void run() {

            try{
                sleep(1000);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                startActivity(new Intent( getApplicationContext(), Main.class));
                finish();
            }//end finaly

        }// end run

    };// end thread 

    splash_screen.start();

}// end method

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_edoc_dc, menu);
    return true;
}


 }
```

and this is its activity_edoc_dc.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_final" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

here is the main.java which is to be loaded after it
package com.example.edoc_dc;

```
     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.os.Bundle;

     public class Main extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // adding the desktop to it
    setContentView(R.layout.main_desktop);

}// end on create
   }// end main
```

and here is its xml file  main_desktop.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="HERE IS THE DESKTOP"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

   </LinearLayout>
```

here is my manifest file

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.edoc_dc"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Edoc_dc"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_edoc_dc" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

  </manifest>
```

please solve the problem and tell what to do.. the application is working fine just got crash before foing to the main screen

Comment: Please read your logs error before posting a question here, cause the answer is in your logs. An advice for next time ;).

Answer (score 3):

You have not made an entry for activity main in manifest file

```
<activity
    android:name=".Main"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_edoc_dc" >   
</activity>
```

Using sleep inside a thread is not a good design.

If you implement `Thread` or `HandlerThread`, be sure that your UI thread does not block while waiting for the worker thread to complete— `do not call Thread.wait()` or `Thread.sleep()`.

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

You can use a handler

```
   private static final int SPLASH_TIME = 2 * 1000;// 3 seconds
```

Handler

```
   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

          Intent intent = new Intent(Edoc_dc.this,Main.class);
            startActivity(intent);

           Edoc_dc.this.finish();
        }    

    }, SPLASH_TIME);
```

Note: Some people consider splash screen as evil especially if does nothing (just a delay).

http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/

Comment: It is true that it is more elegant! Good to know

Answer (score 1):

You didn't have declare your file Main.java into your Manifest file as an activity like the error say here :

```
06-12 14:34:46.280: E/AndroidRuntime(25510): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:  
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.edoc_dc/com.example.edoc_dc.Main}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
06-12 14:34:46.280: E/AndroidRuntime(25510): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.edoc_dc/com.example.edoc_dc.Main}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

This looks like to be a problem ,check in your manifest, have you declared this Activity with Proper name/package

Comment: thanks sooo much ... perfact anwer... just added the activity and worked..!!! thanks agian

Answer (score 0):

As LogCat says, it seems like you haven't declared your Activity "Main" in the Manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

The error is written in all letter in your logcat:

```
06-12 14:35:12.360: E/AndroidRuntime(25869): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.edoc_dc/com.example.edoc_dc.Main}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

**All activities** of your application must be defined in the `AndroidManifest`. You are trying to show an activity Main which is not

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared your Main activity in Manifest.thats why it is throwing ActivityNotFoundException.

Declare this-

```
<activity
        android:name=".Main">

</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your error log:

```
"06-12 14:35:12.360: E/AndroidRuntime(25869): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.edoc_dc/com.example.edoc_dc.Main};
have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?"
```

You have to add this block in your manifest file:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.edoc_dc.Main"/>
```

just before < /application > tag

This is the declaration of your main activity.

Answer (score 0):

Your logcat says it all:

```
06-12 14:34:46.280: E/AndroidRuntime(25510): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.edoc_dc/com.example.edoc_dc.Main}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Try declaring the main activity in your manifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.edoc_dc.Main" </activity>
```

Also : [more info on splashscreens](http://blog.iangclifton.com/2011/01/01/android-splash-screens-done-right/)

Also: [don't use splashscreens, it's an iOS thing :)](http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/)

Cheers, hope I helped.